# Get content of Multi-Line text field in Sharepoint 2010 Data Services

Tags: 2010, web-services, wcf

I am using listdata.svc service to retrieve data from Sharepoint 2010

I have a List and it has a Multi-Line text field which has append option on.

when you append text to multi-line text field, it adds timespamp and the user who add the text.

However, when O try to interrogate the field via data services, it only returns the content of the last added entry.

is it the expected behaviour or kind of bug?

thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the implementation of the Appending Multi-line text field I'd say that it's expected behaviour. Is it what most users want? NO, but that's what you get.

The value of a Appending Multi-line text field is in fact only the last added entry. when rendering it SharePoint retrieves the value (and timestamp/user) from previous versions. You can verify that by deleting a previous version.

To make things even worse you can't get the previous versions using the Client Side Object Model, but have to resort to the old Web Services [Lists.GetListItemChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.getlistitemchanges.aspx)